# How to call object's methods using a function pointer?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, visual-studio-2017

I'd like to call a few methods of classes 'A' and 'B' from the class 'Caller'. I need to use a function pointer because I want to call different methods.

My method gets called, but when I try to access a member variable from it, my program crashes ('program.exe has stopped working').

How come that happens?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <class T>
class Caller
{
    typedef void (T::*myFunc)(int);
    public: 
        Caller(T* obj, myFunc fp)
        {
            f = fp;
        }
        void invoke(int foobar)
        {
            (o->*f)(foobar);
        }
    private:
        myFunc f;
        T* o;
};

class A
{
    public:
        A() : n(0) {}
        void foo(int bar)
        {
            cout << "A::foo called (bar = " << bar << ", n = " << n << ")" << endl; // the crash occurs here, and 'this' equals 0 at this point
        }
        void setNum(int num)
        {
            n = num;
        }
    private:
        int n;
};

class B
{
    public:
        B() : n(0) {}
        void fooo(int bar)
        {
            cout << "B::fooo called (bar = " << bar << ", n = " << n << ")" << endl; // same here if I call B::fooo first
        }
        void setNum(int num)
        {
            n = num;
        }
    private:
        int n;
};

int main()
{
    A myA;
    B myB;

    myA.setNum(128);
    myB.setNum(256);

    Caller<A> cA(&myA, &A::foo);
    Caller<B> cB(&myB, &B::fooo);

    cA.invoke(10);
    cB.invoke(20);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT : I use VS2017 and I can build my program without getting any compiler errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My method gets called, but when I try to access a member variable from it, my program crashes ...

Because you forgot to assign passed `obj` to `o` pointer in your `Caller`:

```
template <class T>
class Caller
{
    typedef void (T::*myFunc)(int);
public:
    Caller(T* obj, myFunc fp)
    {
        o = obj;  // << == you need this!
        f = fp;
    }
    void invoke(int foobar)
    {
        (o->*f)(foobar);
    }
private:
    myFunc f;
    T* o;
};
```

Also, in general it's better to use [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
Caller::Caller(T* obj, myFunc fp) : o(obj), f(fp)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pavel !! Now it works like a charm ! I can't believe I made such a silly mistake... And thank you for your advice. I also wonder if I can store and call only my method? I mean without its object

Comment: You cannot call non static method without any object, it simply doesn't make sense. If you make it static, then you can call it just like any other non-member function.

Comment: Okay I get it now. Thank you very much Pavel.